# Powershell email not including attachment?

Tags: powershell, email

I am trying to set up a batch file which will call a Powershell and ultimately send a file on the users computer to a given email address. While I can get the email to send, it always sends without the attachment included.

The batch file code i have is:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\Users\attachment2.ps1
```

and the Powershell code I have is:

```
$attachment = "C:\Users\SearchResults\37.csv" 

$EmailFrom = "david@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "john@gmail.com"
$Subject = "The subject of your email"
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment) 
$message.Attachments.Add($attach) 
$Body = "This is just a test mail to verify the working of CMD"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxxx");
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $attach, $Body)
```

If anyone knows as to why the attachment is not being included it would be of great help. I have looked at other examples on stackoverflow as well as other sites but have been not able to fix my own code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just because you invoked a Powershell script from batch file does not mean you should be spamming that tag. I've now removed it.

Comment: I don't see `$message` defined, or really used. The `SmtpClient.Send(string, string, string, string)` method does not support attachments, you would need to create a mail object then send that with the smtpclient. But really, why are you not just using `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: I am sorry I am still new to this, I have now tried to implement the ```Send-MailMessage``` method but am now having trouble connecting to the server.

Comment: The code I have is ```$from = "blondedavid@gmail.com"
$to = "blondedavid@gmail.com"
$subject = "The subject of your email"
$body = "This is just a test mail to verify the working of CMD"
$smtp = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("blondedavid@gmail", "pswrd");
$attachment="C:\Users\SearchResults\37.csv"

send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Attachment $attachment -Priority high  ```